# How to disable CORB in Chrome 74+

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, cross-origin-read-blocking

I want to debug a local dev environment issue potentially caused by CORB in Chrome 74. I want to see if - when I swith off CORB - the issue goes away.

The according [Google developer docs](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers) say that

> You can confirm if a problem is due to CORB by temporarily disabling it, by starting Chrome with the following command line flag:
>   --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating

However, if I run

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingAlways,CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating --user-data-dir="C:/ChromeDevSession"
```

Chrome still shows CORB warnings and blocks according requests.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at mentioned in the docs [feature tracking page](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768) you will find link to [tracking bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=802835). The last commit in that bug actually refers to revision where this [feature is enabled by default and is no more controlled from outside](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1228485/) through command line (at least using mentioned in the question flags).

But there is interesting piece of code added :

```
  // --disable-web-security also disables Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB).
  if (base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(
          switches::kDisableWebSecurity)) {
    params->is_corb_enabled = false;
    return;
  }
```

Hopefully in 74 version it still exist. So if you OK with all consequences just add 
`--disable-web-security` instead.

By the way in [latest sources](https://cs.chromium.org) you will not find it anymore. So with never version of chromium you will not be able to disable it.